# C# cannot return cause it has wrong return type

Tags: c#

I started programming recently and I have troubles. I was wondering how to use `int`, `double` and `string` with delegates. Every time I mix them I get error CS0407. I have some samples but they only use `int` inside delegates. Thanks in advance.

```cs
using System;

namespace _8pirmas
{
    class Program
    {
        public delegate string IsvedimoEiliskumas(string v, string p, string s, int am, int pat);

        static string vardas(string a, string b, string c, int d, int e) { return a; }
        static string pavarde(string a, string b, string c,int d, int e) { return b; }
        static string specialybe(string a, string b, string c,int d, int e) { return c; }
        static int amzius(string a, string b, string c, int d, int e) { return d; }
        static int patirtis(string a, string b, string c, int d, int e) { return e; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IsvedimoEiliskumas[] funkcija = new IsvedimoEiliskumas[3];
      
            string v, p, s;
            int am, pat;
 
            int pasirinkimas = 1;

            Console.WriteLine($"Įveskite darbuotojo informaciją.");
        
            v = Console.ReadLine();
            p = Console.ReadLine();
            s = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Įveskite amžių: ");
            am = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Įveskite stažą: ");
            pat = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine($"Kaip norėtumėte išdėstyti šią informaciją?");
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{i + 1} zingsnis: (1)Vardas, (2)Pavarde, (3)Specialybe, 
(4)Amzius, (5)Patirtis, (6)Atlyginimas");
                pasirinkimas = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                switch(pasirinkimas)
                {
                    case 1: funkcija[i] = vardas; break;
                    case 2: funkcija[i] = pavarde; break;
                    case 3: funkcija[i] = specialybe; break;
                    case 4: funkcija[i] = amzius; break;
                    case 5: funkcija[i] = patirtis; break;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i< 3; i++)
                Console.WriteLine($"Atsakymas {i + 1} veiksmo { funkcija[i](v, p, s, am , pat)}");
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have declared a delegate that returns `string`. You are trying to give it a function that returns `int`. The error message tells you about it. What do you think should be happening instead?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on Stack Overflow, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SO to distribute that content. By SO policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, please read more at [How does deleting work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

Let's have a look at `specialybe` and `amzius` methods.

```
 static string specialybe(string a, string b, string c,int d, int e) ...
 static int amzius(string a, string b, string c, int d, int e) ...
```

These methods have different signatures (one returns string the other int) so you cannot mix and match them.

Since you're using the response only as text a good hack would be to `.ToString()` `d` & `e` which would allow keeping the signatures of all methods the same.

```
 static string specialybe(string a, string b, string c,int d, int e) { return c; }
 static string amzius(string a, string b, string c, int d, int e) { return d.ToString(); }
 static string patirtis(string a, string b, string c, int d, int e) { return e.ToString(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

`delegates` are like method interfaces: you have to match their exact signature, including the return type. Since the return type of delegate `IsvedimoEiliskumas` is `string`, any method that fulfills the delegate must also have return type `string` (as well as all the same method parameter types, in order).

From your code `amzius` and `patirtis` have a different return type (`int`) than `IsvedimoEiliskumas`. To resolve this issue, you have two options:

#### 1. Change the fulfilling method signatures' return type

Change `amzius` and `patirtis` so that they return a `string`. The simplest implementation would look like this:

```cs
static string amzius(string a, string b, string c, int d, int e) { return d.ToString(); }
static string patirtis(string a, string b, string c, int d, int e) { return e.ToString(); }
```

#### 2. Make your delegate generic

To support multiple return types in your delegate, make it generic:

```cs
public delegate T IsvedimoEiliskumas<T>(string v, string p, string s, int am, int pat);
```

You can now return whatever you want from a method or lambda fulfilling `IsvedimoEiliskumas`. The downside is, in your example, you have to specify a concrete type in your declaration of `funkcija` **and you will still need to change your fulfilling methods to match its signature:**

```cs
// Still errors on amzius and patirtis, and you have same issue
IsvedimoEiliskumas<string>[] funkcija = new IsvedimoEiliskumas<string>[3];

// Now errors on vardas, pavarde, and specialybe instead
IsvedimoEiliskumas<int>[] funkcija = new IsvedimoEiliskumas<int>[3];

// Errors on everything, but we are more abstract than string or int
IsvedimoEiliskumas<object>[] funkcija = new IsvedimoEiliskumas<object>[3];
```

To make this work, you would need to change every method used in `funkcija` to have return type `object`. You could then cast it to the original type when needed.

**Side note:** in situations where you only use a method to fulfill a delegate, you can construct an instance of the delegate directly as a lambda:

```cs
static IsvedimoEiliskumas vardas = (a, b, c, d, e) => a;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your delegate have a return type of a **string**, and in your last two methods you put the return type as **int**

[image]

If you dont have the **Visual Studio** already, please install, is worth it. There you have the error on the IDE (i.e Visual Studio).

[image]